# `WKWebsiteDataStore.default()` crash if the code is access before any webview is accessed. Why?

Tags: ios

I have the following code

```
      let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/set_simple.php")!
      let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
      let session = URLSession.shared
      session.configuration.httpCookieAcceptPolicy = .always
      session.configuration.httpCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
      session.configuration.httpShouldSetCookies = true
      let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
          if error == nil {
            print("Success fetch!")
            guard
                let url = response?.url,
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                let fields = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String: String]
            else { return }
            let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: fields, for: url)
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL: nil)
            for cookie in cookies {
                var cookieProperties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]()
                cookieProperties[.name] = cookie.name
                cookieProperties[.value] = cookie.value
                cookieProperties[.domain] = cookie.domain
                cookieProperties[.path] = cookie.path
                cookieProperties[.version] = cookie.version
                cookieProperties[.expires] = Date().addingTimeInterval(31536000)
                let newCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)
//                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(newCookie!)
                WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.setCookie(newCookie!, completionHandler: nil)
                print("name: \(cookie.name) value: \(cookie.value)")
            }
              
          } else {
            print("Ops! \(error.debugDescription)")
          }
      }
      dataTask.resume()
```

It works well if I only access it, after accessing a webview.

However, if I start the app and access this code before accessing any webview, it will crash at `WKWebsiteDataStore.default()`. Is it because I need to setup the `WKWebsiteDataStore` default?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like I need to set it on the mainThread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.setCookie(newCookie!, completionHandler: nil)
}
```